# TListView.OnAdvancedCustomDraw issue with selected row

Tags: delphi, ownerdrawn, tlistview

my Delphi Berlin app shall get a TListView in report mode and one of the columns shall get painted something in the background. For a first test this looks like the following code, but in the end the actual drawing code will not always fill the whole subitem. But it shouldn't matter for the issue at hand.

The problem now is, that while it usually works it changes all text in a row I select or hover with the mout over into black rectangles. if the mouse leaves the row or it is getting unselected text goes back to normal.

OS is Windows 7.

```
procedure TMyForm.ListView1AdvancedCustomDraw(Sender: TCustomListView; 
    const ARect: TRect; Stage: TCustomDrawStage; 
    var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
  ColLeft: Integer;
  ColBounds: TRect;
  I: Integer;
begin
  DefaultDraw := true;
  Stage := cdPrePaint;

  ColLeft := 0;
  for i := 0 to 2 do
    ColLeft := ColLeft + ListView1.Columns[i].Width;

  ColBounds := Rect(
    ColLeft,
    ARect.Top,
    ColLeft + ListView1.Columns[3].Width,
    ARect.Bottom
  );

  ListView1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  ListView1.Canvas.FillRect(ColBounds);
end;
```

Comment: Read the nice [manual](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomDrawStage) before using `Stage`.

Comment: Painting only when Stage = cdPostPaint fixes this, but now I figured out that this event is not the right one anyway, as it would draw also in the space where no rows are and we don't have the information which row we're in either, so I can't let values from that row influence my painting. The other events don't work for me as well, as always some information I'd need is missing.
Looks like I need to go for TVirtualTreeView. There I know I can do what I like to.